# $f(z) = 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| = 1 \implies f(z) = 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know whether this statement is true or not:

> If $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic such that $f(z) = 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z| = 1$, then $f$ is constant with $f(z) = 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

My guess is that this statement holds. Still, I struggle to proof it, mainly because the set $M := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}$ is no domain. However, considering a domain (or at least an open set) is a basic assumption for almost every theorem that states something about constant holomorphic functions.

Comment: The domain of $f$ *is* open

Comment: The claim follows from the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: It's ok that M is no domain. It's sufficient that it has an accumulation point. See [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb C$ is connected, and since $S^1$ has non-isolated points (actually, *none* of its points is isolated), it follows from the identity theorem that$$\left(\forall z\in S^1\right):f(z)=1\implies(\forall z\in\Bbb C):f(z)=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$1-f$ is $0$ over the non-discrete subset $S^1$, therefore it is constant $0$.